# Testing in Maven

Tags: maven, import

So I have a project in Maven, with the tree structure it made and the code completed.
Now Im in the test phase and supposedly (if I am not wrong) I have to use the `AppTest.java` in the test branch of the project.

The thing is that the classes I need to test are in the "main" branch of the project.

How do I import them so that the test can be performed?

EDIT:

Yes, with branch I wasnt referring to anything version control related but about the location in the folders maven autogenerates (given the tree view of the folders used by Eclipse).

ANSWER:

As Aaron Digulla said, I could import them as usual.

It was enough with "import domain.NameOfClass;"

It complained about not being able to autocomplete the route when I typed the dot, but ignoring it was the way to go since it ended up working. 
Maven took care of that.

Comment: Why have you separated unit testing from usual code by a branch? Does not make sense.

Comment: @Erchz: With "branch", do you mean a folder on your hard disk or a branch in your version control system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import them as usual. When running the tests, Maven will create a classpath which will make everything in `src/main/java` visible to the test classes.